# Ember CLI strict mode

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-11

I developed an Ember CLI software which runs fine in IE9 and Chrome. But in IE11 I get an error "undefined variable in strict mode". Can I deactivate the strict mode in Ember CLI or what do I have to do so that my app runs in IE11?

Comment: I resolved all JSHint-Errors, now the app is working in IE11. But anyway, is it possible to dissable strict mode?

Comment: I believe it is not possible, ES2015 modules are by spec strict mode.

Comment: `"use strict";` is valid syntax in ES5. So it shouldn't harm.